# Proving the cardinality of $|A| =|\mathbb Z|$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A=\{ (2n,-3n)~|~ n\in \mathbb Z\}$. Prove that $|A| =|\mathbb Z|$.

What would an example of a function, $f:\mathbb{Z}\to A$? Would it be something like $f(x)=(2x,-3x)$?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes just show that $f$ is injective.

Comment: If something is enumerated by another set $I$ it has cardinality at most that of such set, for there is a surjection from $I$ to such enumerated set. Since in your case your set is at most countable and infinite, it is countably infinite.

Comment: @ruberto so something like $f(x)=f(y)$, $(2x, -3x)=(2y,-3y)$, $(x,x)=(y,y)$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $$
f:\Bbb Z\to A\\
n\mapsto(2n,-3n)$$

Suppose $f(n)=f(m)$, then $(2n,-3n)=(2m,-3m)$, so  $2n=2m, -3n=-3m$, etc, so $n=m$.

Also, let $k\in A$, then $k=(2n,-3n)$ **for some integer $n$**, then $f(n)=k$.

Thus $f$ is bijective, and we're done.

Comment: I'd say that the new function $g$ is unnecessary. By the way $A$ is defined the function $f$ is already surjective

Comment: @leibnewtz ugh. Of course, thanks.

Comment: @leibnewtz Do I have to define a new function $g$? isn't $f$ also surjective? I just can't seem to figure that out.

Comment: @Alfredo Yes, $f$ is, that step was unnecessary, I've edited.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD how does surjective come to be? I'm seeing the setup, but how do we solve for $n$?

Comment: Well, are you asking for the general case or this particular one? You just got to pick and arbitrary element from $A$ (here $k$), and use some strategy to deduce if there's any integer $m$ such that $f(m)=k$. Here we used that as $k\in A$, it needs to have a particular look, and that gave us our required $m$ (here, that's what I called in the answer '$n$').

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD This case in particular, I think its the ordered set that's confusing me

Answer (score 0):

An easy way of showing that they have the same cardinality would be to construct a function, say $f$, from one to the other and show that it has an inverse. This would show that $f$ is a bijection. Meaning for every element in one set there is a unique element in the other corresponding to it. This means they have the same amount of 'stuff'. Hence, they have the same cardinality. So now time for a hint...

HINT: You already have a function $f: \mathbb{Z} \to A$ given by $f(n)=(2n,-3n)$. Now can you think of a function, say $g$, from $A$ to $\mathbb{Z}$? Guess one! Then check to see if $f(g(x))=x$ and $g(f(x))=x$. If so, $g$ is the inverse to $f$ and you are done!